How do I solve the issue of getting a 403 forbidden when I send a POST request that creates a new user
Even though I permitted the path in the config class, I still get 403 forbidden when I send a POST request through Postman. If I disable Spring Security (permitting all requests), the request kinda works.
I get this message on the terminal:
2024-12-19T00:21:09.253+01:00 DEBUG 15372 --- [backend-2in1-project] [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /api/v1/auth/register
2024-12-19T00:21:09.253+01:00 DEBUG 15372 --- [backend-2in1-project] [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2024-12-19T00:21:09.253+01:00 DEBUG 15372 --- [backend-2in1-project] [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint     : Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access

The config class
package com.momentstock.backend._in1.project.security;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter;
import org.modelmapper.ModelMapper;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AbstractHttpConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;

import java.util.List;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
//@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true) // to enable @preAuthorize
public class SecurityConfig {
    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    private final JwtAuthFilter jwtAuthFilter;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .cors(cors -> cors.configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource()))
                .authorizeHttpRequests(con -> con
                                .requestMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers("/users/**").hasRole("USER")
                                .requestMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                                .requestMatchers("/api/v1/orders/payment/callback").permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers("/welcome/**").permitAll()
//              .requestMatchers("/testKey").permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/users/user/me/delete-account").authenticated()
                                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
//              .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth .anyRequest().permitAll())

                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(List.of(
                "https://api.flutterwave.com",
                "https://api.paystack.co",
                "https://sandbox.interswitchng.com"
        ));
        configuration.addAllowedOrigin("*");
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(List.of("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("*")); // Allow all headers
        configuration.setExposedHeaders(List.of("Authorization", "Content-Type")); // Optional, expose specific headers
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);

        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration); // Apply to all endpoints
        return source;
    }
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration configuration) throws Exception {
        return configuration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }
    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authProvider;
    }
    @Bean
    public ModelMapper modelmapper(){
        return new ModelMapper();
    }

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }


}

The controller:
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping("${api.prefix}/auth")
public class UserAuthController {
    private final IUserService userService;
    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final VerificationTokenRepository tokenRepository;
    private final JwtTokenProvider tokenProvider;

    @PostMapping("/register")
    public ResponseEntity<String> registerUser(@RequestBody CreateUserRequest request){
        userService.registerUser(request);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body("User created successfully, check your email complete verification");
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<ApiResponse> loginUser(@RequestBody LoginRequest request){
        try {
            LoginResponse loginResponse = userService.loginUser(request);
            return ResponseEntity.ok(new ApiResponse("Success", loginResponse));
        } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(BAD_REQUEST).body(new ApiResponse(e.getMessage(), null));
        }
    }

The UserDetails:
package com.momentstock.backend._in1.project.security;

import com.momentstock.backend._in1.project.enums.Role;
import com.momentstock.backend._in1.project.models.User;
import lombok.Data;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Data
public class UserRegDetails implements UserDetails {

    private String userName;
    private String password;
    private boolean isEnabled;
    private Role role;

    public UserRegDetails(User user) {
        this.userName = user.getEmail();
        this.password = user.getPassword();
        this.isEnabled = user.isEnabled();
        this.role = Role.valueOf(user.getRole().name());
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return role != null
                ? List.of(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.name().toUpperCase()))
                : List.of();
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return userName;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
//      return UserDetails.super.isAccountNonExpired();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
//      return UserDetails.super.isAccountNonLocked();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
//      return UserDetails.super.isCredentialsNonExpired();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
//      return UserDetails.super.isEnabled();
        return isEnabled;
    }
}

The service
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserRegDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        return userRepository.findByEmail(email).map(UserRegDetails::new).orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found"));
    }
}


there is a lot of information missing what is IUserService? You have cut off the logs so whe have no idea what happens before or after your problem. Also handing out JWTTokens straight to browsers is not recommended, its dangerous so why are you doing this? And why are you building some kind of homemade security and why does not the built in security solutions that come with spring security work for you as they work in 95% of the cases. Spring security is a framework with built in logins, why cant you use them?

IUserService is an interface

i know what an interface is, and that you have named it the way you name interfaces in C# but whats the reason for asking for help but not posting the implementation.

I have a new class that configures the whole CORS topic:


@Configuration
public class CorsConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

  protected static final String[] CORS_ORIGIN_DOMAIN_PROPERTY_KEYS = {
    "cors.allowed.origin",
    "cors.allowed.origin.public"
  };
  @Autowired
  private Environment env;

  /**
   * Configuration of cors.
   * @return WebMvcConfigurer
   */
  @Bean
  public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
      @Override
      public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
          .allowedOrigins(getAllAvailableOrigins())
          .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "HEAD", "OPTIONS")
          .allowedHeaders("*")
          .allowCredentials(true);
      }
    };
  }

  private String[] getAllAvailableOrigins() {
    List < String > originList = new ArrayList < > ();
    for (String key: CORS_ORIGIN_DOMAIN_PROPERTY_KEYS) {
      String domain = env.getProperty(key);
      if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(domain)) {
        String[] domainArray = domain.split(",");
        originList.addAll(Arrays.asList(domainArray));
      }
    }
    return originList.toArray(new String[] {});
  }

}



where "cors.allowed.origin" and "cors.allowed.origin.public" are values configured in the "application.properties" file. A value from those can be:
cors.allowed.origin=http://localhost:4200,https://something.somethingElse.com
Hope it helps,
Adrian

why would he implement CORS using WebMvcConfigurer when its not an MVC application? I suggest you read the CORS chapter in the spring security documentation
